# Issue in importing the Firestore and implementing addOnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the Cloud firestore for saving the user data. I am trying out the example shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Could you please let me know what is missing ?

**dependencies in build file**

```
dependencies {
    api files('libs/AudienceNetwork.jar')
    api files('libs/FacebookAdapter.jar')

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5'

}
```

**Imports**

```
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener; 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration; 

import com.facebook.ads.Ad;
import com.facebook.ads.AdError;
import com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import SQLLib.SqlHelper;
import data.AltcoinCoinEntry;
import data.Coin;
import data.CoinListing;
import data.Ico;
import data.News;
import data.Portfolio;
import data.PrefCoinEntry;
import data.SmartURL;
import data.Tran;
import data.TranEntry;
import util.IabHelper;
import util.IabResult;
import util.Inventory;
import util.Purchase;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, there is one more class and one more interface that you need to import in order to call `addOnSuccessListener()` on a `CollectionReference` object and pass a `OnSuccessListener` object as an argument.

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
```

Comment: what should be there in the dependency ?  I have this dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.5' 
}

Comment: No, this should be placed in your activity class right below the other two from your question. Does it work now?

Comment: Yes I have added but I am unable to import. I think it need some dependency setup in gradle

Comment: please check the question, I have added the 2 additional imports

Comment: Please add the content of your both build.gradle files. And a screenshot with all imports.

Comment: Added the import and gradle dependency. Only thing is I am unable to import the file com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;